# Selecting columns of dataset without using the number of the column but the name of the column

Tags: r, select

I tried to select columns of dataset without using the index number of the column but the name of the column

```
data(iris)
y<-iris[, colnames = "Species"]
z<-iris[, colnames != "Species"]
```

Can anyone tell why line 2 & 3 are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `colnames` is a function, you need to call functions with `()`. `colnames` needs a dataframe or matrix as input. So you need to use `colnames(iris)` to get the column names of `iris` dataset.
2. `=` is an assignment operator. What you need here is comparison operator which is `==`.

```
y<-iris[, colnames(iris) == "Species", drop = FALSE]
z<-iris[, colnames(iris) != "Species"]
```

When subsetting a dataframe if the output is only of 1 column R drops its dimension and you get output as a vector. To keep data as dataframe in `y` we use `drop = FALSE`.